# Continuous random variables word problem

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

I'm having difficulty with a word problem on continuous random variables. Would you be able to help? Here it is:

If you're n minutes early for an appointment, then you are charged n times 3 dollars, but if you are n minutes late, you are charged n times 5 dollars. If the travel time from your home and the appointment location is a continuous random variable with pdf f(x) such that f(x) = (1/10)e^(-x/10) if x >= 0 and f(x) = 0 if x < 0. How many minutes before your appointment should you leave to minimize fees?

What should I do with the probability density function. Should I be finding the Expected Value for it?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a homework problem, and if so, please add the `homework` tag.

An important notion to get a firm grip on is that if $X$ is a random variable, and $g(\cdot)$ is a *measurable* function (all functions that you are likely to encounter in this probability course will be measurable), then $g(X) = Y$ is a *random variable* 
(a *function* of the random variable $X$) and the 
expected value of this random variablecan be computed as 
$$E[Y] = E[g(X)] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)f_X(x)\,\mathrm dx$$
without needing to find $f_Y(y)$ and then using
$$E[Y] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty y f_Y(y)\, \mathrm dy$$
as the definition of expectation says you should. This result is sometimes
referred to as the [Law of the Unconscious Statistician](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician), LOTUS for short.
In particular, $g(\cdot)$ need not be expressible by a single formula.  With this in
mind, suppose that you leave $T$ minutes before your appointment and arrive $X$ minutes
later, then you pay a fine of $3(T-X)$ if $X < T$, and you pay a fine of $5(X-T)$ if 
$X > T$.  So, consider the function 
$$g(x) = \begin{cases} 3(T-x), & 0 \leq x \leq T,\\
5(x-T), & T < x < \infty,\\
0, &x < 0.\end{cases}$$
which results in
$$g(X) = \text{fine you have to pay if you leave}~ T~\text{before your appointment}$$
is a *random variable* whose value depends on $X$. Can you use LOTUS to find the
expected value or *average* value of $g(X)$? $E[g(X)]$ will work out to
be a *function* of $T$,
which you can choose.  What value of $T$ will minimize your *average* fine?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I haven't heard of LOTUS before. To find E[g(X)], can I do the integral of g(x) * f(x) dx with lower limit 0 and upper limit infinity?